# How to display a Google Maps Android Marker on top of the others?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

I have multiple markers in my application, sometimes some of them are at the same position. I want some of those markers to be always displayed in front of the others. How should I proceed ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is the wrong approach. Even if you put one marker in front of the other there is still a possibility that the user will click the marker that is behind.

I would instead of doing that, on adding a new `Marker` to the map, check if there is already a `Marker` at the newly added `Marker` location, if yes just added the new data to the current `Marker` and don't added another one.

that way the same marker will represent both specified locations.

**UPDATE:**

Take a look at this code, in it I check if the currently clicked marker is my current location.
And this way I know if I should fire up a directions activity or not. You can use the same technic to find out if you already have a marker at specific location.

```
 map.setInfoWindowAdapter(new InfoWindowAdapter() {

            // Use default InfoWindow frame
            @Override
            public View getInfoWindow(Marker args) {
                return null;
            }

            // Defines the contents of the InfoWindow
            @Override
            public View getInfoContents(Marker args) {

                // Getting view from the layout file info_window_layout
                View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.info_window_layout, null);

                // Getting the position from the marker
                clickMarkerLatLng = args.getPosition();

                TextView title = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
                title.setText(args.getTitle());

                map.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new OnInfoWindowClickListener() {          
                    public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) 
                    {
                        if (SGTasksListAppObj.getInstance().currentUserLocation!=null)
                        {   
                            if (String.valueOf(SGTasksListAppObj.getInstance().currentUserLocation.getLatitude()).substring(0, 8).contains(String.valueOf(clickMarkerLatLng.latitude).substring(0, 8)) &&
                                    String.valueOf(SGTasksListAppObj.getInstance().currentUserLocation.getLongitude()).substring(0, 8).contains(String.valueOf(clickMarkerLatLng.longitude).substring(0, 8)))
                            {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "This your current location, navigation is not needed.",  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                FlurryAgent.onEvent("Start navigation window was clicked from daily map");
                                tasksRepository = SGTasksListAppObj.getInstance().tasksRepository.getTasksRepository();
                                for (Task tmptask : tasksRepository)
                                {
                                    String tempTaskLat = String.valueOf(tmptask.getLatitude());
                                    String tempTaskLng = String.valueOf(tmptask.getLongtitude());

                                    Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(tmptask.getLatitude())+","+String.valueOf(clickMarkerLatLng.latitude).substring(0, 8));

                                    if (tempTaskLat.contains(String.valueOf(clickMarkerLatLng.latitude).substring(0, 8)) && tempTaskLng.contains(String.valueOf(clickMarkerLatLng.longitude).substring(0, 8)))
                                    {  
                                        task = tmptask;
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }
                                /*
                                findDirections(SGTasksListAppObj.getInstance().currentUserLocation.getLatitude(),
                                               SGTasksListAppObj.getInstance().currentUserLocation.getLongitude(),
                                               clickMarkerLatLng.latitude, clickMarkerLatLng.longitude, GMapV2Direction.MODE_DRIVING );
                                */
                                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext() ,RoadDirectionsActivity.class);
                                intent.putExtra(TasksListActivity.KEY_ID, task.getId());
                                startActivity(intent);

                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your current location could not be found,\nNavigation is not possible.",  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });

                // Returning the view containing InfoWindow contents
                return v;

            }
        });
```

Comment: You're probably right, this is how I'll do it. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Just another question, do you know if there is any quick way to check if there is a Marker at a given location, or do I need to make my own function ?

Answer (score 7):

marker.setZIndex(Float.MAX_VALUE)

Answer (score 0):

In android compose map you can use **zIndex** to give it a value in float
By default **zIndex = 0** for markers you have not specified zIndex for. Adding any value more then 0 would make the marker float above rest.

```
 MarkerInfoWindow(
        zIndex = 5f,
        state = MarkerState(position = position),
        onClick = {...},
        icon = icon,
        onInfoWindowClick = {...},
        title = "your title here"
    )
```

Answer (score -1):

You should sort them in some way and last one in adapter will be on top.

Answer (score -1):

Select the ones you want to be allways visible, and add them to the map last.