# Android Google Maps OnMapClickListeners

Tags: android, google-maps, onclick, google-maps-markers

Hie everyone I have this code and what it does it adds a marker on the map everytime I click on the map. Anyone knows how I could add a title for that marker as well and make the marker constant so the next time that the activity will run the marker would be on the place that I clicked before. For now if i rerun the activity the marker disappears. Anyone knows how could I implement those 2 things ? Many thanks.

```
          gMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onMapClick(LatLng position) {



            gMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(position));

        }
    });
         }
```

Comment: What u tried? post it all.

Comment: please visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16054719/how-to-display-a-google-maps-android-marker-on-top-of-the-others  and  http://www.androidhive.info/2013/08/android-working-with-google-maps-v2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using this code you can add title and icon to marker.

```
gMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(position).title("your title").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory                                          
                               .fromResource(R.drawable.icon));
```

**I did not get your second problem. Can you explain it?**

Answer (score 0):

```
//make a static class that will contain your marker and map so that it will not be reloaded
public class MarkerData{
  public static Marker marker;
  public static GoogleMap map;
}

public class MyActivity extends Activity{

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundles b){

    if(MarkerData.map == null)
      MarkerData.map = ((SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

    if(MarkerData.marker == null)
      MarkerData.marker = new MarkerOptions().position(position);

    MarkerData.map.addMarker(MarkerData.marker);        

  }
}
```

Comment: The method addMarker(MarkerOptions) in the type GoogleMap is not applicable for the arguments (Marker)